# reshape dataframe in the required format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the dataframe which looks like this:

```
 b = {'STORE_ID': ['1234','5678','9876','3456','6789'],
      'FULFILLMENT_TYPE': 
                 ['DELIVERY','DRIVE','DELIVERY','DRIVE','DELIVERY'], 

      'LAUNCH_DT':['2020-10-01','2020-10-02','2020-10-03','2020-10-04','2020-10-01']}

 df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
```

I would want to reshape it to include a daterange as a column in the dataframe

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start=final_forecasts['FORECAST_DATE'].iloc[0], 
end=final_forecasts['FORECAST_DATE'].iloc[-1])
```

I would be getting this daterange from a different dataframe and would like to add it to the dataframe b such that it looks like this:

```
a = {'STORE_ID': ['1234','1234','1234','1234','1234','5678','5678','5678','5678','5678'], 
     'date_range': ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05','2020-08-01', '2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05'], 
     'FULFILLMENT_TYPE':['DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DRIVE','DRIVE','DRIVE','DRIVE','DRIVE'], 
     'LAUNCH_DT':['2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-02','2020-10-02','2020-10-02','2020-10-02','2020-10-02']}
      df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
      df
```

I would need a separate row for each date.. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you add how looks second DataFrame?

Comment: And how looks final Dataframe generated from first and second?

Comment: the final dataframe is what this looks like : a = {'STORE_ID': ['0216','0216','0216','0216','0216'], 
 'date_range': ['2020-08-01', '2020-08-02','2020-08-03','2020-08-04','2020-08-05'], 
 'FULFILLMENT_TYPE':['DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY','DELIVERY'], 
 'LAUNCH_DT':['2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-01','2020-10-01']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a)

Comment: yes, but in first DataFrame is not `STORE_ID=0216`

Comment: ahhh... edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need add same `date_range` to each row of `df_1` use cross join by new DataFrame:

```
df = (df_1.assign(a=1)
          .merge(pd.DataFrame({'date_range':date_range,'a':1}), on='a')
          .drop('a', axis=1))
```